# NodeJS calling function twice generates error

Tags: json, node.js, api

I have a for loop that calls the following function twice:

```
var getJSON = function (url, callback) {
    var http = require('https');
    http.get(url, function (res) {
        var body = '';

        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function () {
            //console.log("Got response: ", body);
            var response = JSON.parse(body);

            return callback(response);
        });

    }).on('error', function (e) {
        console.log("Got error: ", e);
        return callback(-1); 
    });
}
```

The url parameter is at first "https://api.bitok.com/open_api/btc_eur/ticker" and the second time "https://api.bitok.com/open_api/btc_usd/ticker". The callback parameter is just another function that the program should go. The problem is that if it only works the first time (no matter which of both endpoints), the second time is falling and not printing the error, not sure what to do.

EDIT

Here is the for loop where I call the function, I also can't understand what is wrong, "exch.pairs_list.length" is equal to 2.

```
for (var i = 0; i < exch.pairs_list.length; i++) {
    getJSON(url, callback);
}
```

No error is been thrown, the problem is the callback function, it's only been called once, should be twice.

Comment: You'll have to provide more details and an actual reproducible example of the issue. Adding two calls to getJSON with the provided URLs works like a charm, with the callback being correctly called with what look like relevant values. Wouldn't the issue not be in your calling code instead? Also when you say it is "failing", what happens exactly? Do you get any error?

Comment: Same as @jcaron, absolutely nothing wrong with what you described / not reproduceable. More info or code needed here.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your loop calls `getVolume`, which is distinct from the `getJSON` call you provided earlier. Also provide the code for `this.asisgnToList`. Have you added traces in your `getJSON` and `getVolume` functions, as well as in the callback, to see which parts get executed or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry guys, the mistake was very silly, I was trying to print the result before I actually receive response from the API.

Comment: Then please help us keeping SO clean and delete your old answer (it has no future value for other users)

Comment: @Julian, it was deleted.